# GE Oven JB655SKSS won't turn on, but burners work

Tags: kitchens, oven, range

I have GE oven, model JB655SKSS. The burners work, but the oven control board won't turn on. I checked the connection and wiring. There are no signs of burned wires or other damage. There is power in the power outlet. The thermostat has the right resistance. There is a strange voltmeter reading on the control board when plugged in. 250 between neutral and one hot terminal and 250 v between two hot terminals, but no power between another hot terminal and neutral. Do I need to change the control board, or is it something else?

UPD:
Here are photos of the measuring and wiring. The control board has 1 neutral white wire and two hot: red and black. If I disconnect the black hot wire, volt readings become normal
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Please post a picture of the wiring

Comment: Did this installation ever work?

Comment: Probably the power cord is not properly connected to the stove. Please post a photo of the connections.

Comment: I just added photos. The power cord is properly connected. Wrong reading I have only when the control board is connected. Burners work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Your voltmeter readings indicate the the neutral is connected to one of the hot legs instead of to the neutral return.

This could be a wiring error in your service panel, in the outlet, or in the stove. It's not a simple short circuit because it's not tripping any breaker.

Check the three relative voltages at the controller power connector with the controller unplugged, and then at the outlet with the stove unplugged.

If you see proper voltmeter readings in the outlet when the stove is unplugged, then probably the power cord is not properly connected to the stove.

Comment: I already did it. When the stove is unplugged, there are proper voltmeter readings in the outlet. Also, the wiring from the plug to the stove isn't broken. But when I plug it in, I see those wrong readings.

Comment: If you see proper voltmeter readings in the outlet when the stove is unplugged, then probably the power cord is not properly connected to the stove.

Comment: As I said - I checked the wiring from the plug to the stove. Everything is ok. Take a look at the photos.

Comment: My two cents: Your open neutral may be in the control board. You are measuring 250 at neutral, which means it is not acting as a grounded conductor at that point. Since it has no path back to ground, it measures at the voltage of the phase feeding it. When you measure to the other phase, it would get a potential of 250. If the cord is good, and neutral from the panel is good, then the break is further into the unit. If you measure from a good neutral to that point, it would probably read 110.

Answer (score 0):

The neutral wire feeding your appliance is broken somewhere between it and the main panel.
The reason you measure 250v between neutral and one of the hot wires is that the oven controls are connected between neutral and the other hot wire, which makes it appear that they're shorted together.
You can test the wiring to the outlet by hooking up an incandescent bulb (not LED or CFL) from hot to neutral - only use a single bulb to test each hot individually though, not 2 bulbs in series with neutral in the middle, because otherwise you won't actually be testing the neutral.

Comment: If the neutral was broken then OP would not see 250 between neutral and one hot terminal, as he has clearly reported.

Comment: Looks like something with a control board. When I disconnect the black hot wire from the control board, I see proper readings

Comment: @A.I.Breveleri when the the OP has the oven (and its control board) connected, then neutral is connected thru the control board to one of the hots, so yes - seeing 250V from neutral to the other hot is exactly what you'd expect to see.

Comment: @Jhon there's probably nothing wrong with your control board. Your oven is not getting a proper neutral connection. Try the light-bulb test and you'll see. Your burners work because they don't need the neutral.